# How to add Progress Bar in GWT

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt, client, progress-bar

I have configuration implemented. I want to add the progress bar where client can see how much progress have done with configuration. I don't know how to add progress bar. any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you using a widget library? Sencha GXT offers a ready to use progressbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [native progress element](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/). You just need to create the element, IMO the best modern strategy is to do so using the [elemento library](https://github.com/hal/elemento):

```
Elements.body().add(Elements.progress().apply(el -> { el.max = 100; el.value = 80; }));
```

This code will add `<progress max="100" value="80"/>` to the `body`.

Comment: I want to use the step progress bar.

Comment: What is a step progress bar? Add a link please 

Comment: Oh, so you have a tutorial, just follow up. Use elemental and wrap it all into a widget. If you have a concrete doubt about how to do some javascript thing in gwt just ask a new question.

Comment: I have this css working in the html page. I dont know how to call the css file in the UIbinder file.xml